# Uploading pictures to Facebook from iphone app

Tags: iphone, facebook

I'm currently using facebook to post text in the user's wall. I'm wondering if it's possible to post pictures, such as screenshots from my app for example, in the posts, because someone explained me that currently it's only possible to attach pictures from an URL to the post, and not any picture from the iphone.

It's also possible to upload pictures to the user's facebook album ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't for sure how to do it, but the Facebook SDK Api would probably support what you want.

http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

Answer (score 0):

The opensource ShareKit framework - http://www.getsharekit.com/

Does this successfully and easily - You can publish a photo to your wall, and it is added to an album as well.

Great stuff...:)

Oded.